# Return type mismatch and Java compiles

Tags: java, spring, lambda, javac, method-reference

I am curious as to how the below code compiles

```
@Bean(name = "ErrorDecoder")
public ErrorDecoder streamHubErrorDecoder() {
    return FeignException::errorStatus;
}
```

The type of ErrorDecoder https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/codec/ErrorDecoder.java
FeignException is https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/FeignException.java

The bean expect a type of ErrorDecoder and returnType is methodReference and they don't match . How is there no compile error?

Comment: What do you mean _is methodReference and they don't match_? Do you understand how method references are compiled? `FeignException errorStatus(String methodKey, Response response)` very much matches `ErrorDecoder`'s single abstract method, `decode`.

Answer (score 2):

`FeignException::errorStatus`

is essentially equivalent to the lambda

`(s, r) -> FeignException.errorStatus(s, r)`

Where `s` is type `String` and `r` is type `Response`.  Because this lambda method matches the only method that needs to be implemented in the `ErrorDecoder` interface

```
public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response);
```

The compiler is able to turn the statement `FeignException::errorStatus` into an object of an anonymous class that implements `ErrorDecoder` which can be returned successfully in the `streamHubErrorDecoder` method